# How i can resolve this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How i can resolve this differential equation?
$$y'''-y=0$$
I tried this :
If we put $y=Xe^x$ then 
$$X'=Ae^{-3x/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x+\Phi\right)$$
then
$$y'''-y=0 \Leftrightarrow y'-y=Ae^{-x/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x+\Phi\right)$$
but now how i can extract y?

Comment: Do you know how to find the roots of $r^3-1=0$? Coming from the usual Ansatz $y=e^{rx}$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the differential equation $$y’’’-y=0$$ is a third-order [linear differential equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients). The method to solve this is by making use of the roots of the corresponding auxiliary equation: $$z^3-1=0 \equiv (z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0\implies z = \,\,?$$

As the DE is homogenous, the solution is of the form $$y(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{3} c_i e^{z_ix}$$ where the $z_i$’s are the roots of the auxiliary equation.

Comment: @docmat You can accept my answer by ticking the green mark next to my answer.